# Couldn't find an animation entry for "routeAnimation" ("[ERROR ->]<app></app>"): e_Host@0:0, Directive e

Tags: animation, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to put animation between route changes.

My code is as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: [
    './app.css'
  ],
  template: totTemplate,
  host: {
    '[@routeAnimation]': 'true',
    '[style.display]': "'block'",
    '[style.position]': "'absolute'"
  },
  animations: [
    trigger('routerAnimations', [
      state('*', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0}),
        animate(1000)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', animate(1000, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0})))
    ])
  ]
})
```

Html is as follows:

```
<router-outlet [@routerAnimations]="myOutlet.state" #myOutlet></router-outlet>
```

but it throws follows error:

```
main.prod.bundle.js:10 Error: Template parse errors:
Couldn't find an animation entry for "routeAnimation" ("[ERROR ->]<app></app>"): e_Host@0:0, Directive e
    at t.parse (http://localhost:5003/static/vendor.prod.bundle.js:10:471)
    at t._compileTemplate (http://localhost:5003/static/vendor.prod.bundle.js:18:9374)
    at http://localhost:5003/static/vendor.prod.bundle.js:18:6947
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at t._compileComponents (http://localhost:5003/static/vendor.prod.bundle.js:18:6918)
    at i (http://localhost:5003/static/vendor.prod.bundle.js:18:4557)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:5003/static/polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2:26661)
    at e.run (http://localhost:5003/static/polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2:24048)
    at http://localhost:5003/static/polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2:22150
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:5003/static/polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2:27290)(anonymous function) @ main.prod.bundle.js:10t.invoke @ polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2e.run @ polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2(anonymous function) @ polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2t.invokeTask @ polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2e.runTask @ polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2i @ polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2invoke @ polyfills.prod.bundle.js:2
```

Comment: I have exact same error here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template router-outlet you have **@routerAnimations** but in your component you wrote **@routeAnimation** in host (missing 's'). Probably this is the issue.